# Apache 2.4 - How to restrict traffic (by IP address) to all requests except the base path?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-auth, mod-authz-host

I have a collection of debugging scripts in `/var/www` that display useful information that helps with investigating issues on the server, however that same information is potentially sensitive, so I do not want it publicly available.

The `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www/`, which looks like this:

```
$ ls -1 /var/www/
apc.php
index.php
linux-dash
opcache.php
phpinfo.php
```

To secure this information I'm trying to configure apache to only accept requests from my IP address (which for the sake of this example is `192.168.33.1`).

The complication is that I want requests to `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/index.php` to respond with a 200 regardless of which IP they originate from.

My `status.conf` virtual host config currently looks like this:

```
ServerName      www.example.com

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      www.example.com

    DocumentRoot    /var/www
    <Directory      /var/www>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require ip 192.168.33.1
    </Directory>

    <LocationMatch ^/(index.php)?$>
        Require all granted
    </LocationMatch>

    <Location /server-status>
        SetHandler server-status
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is partially working, as it's allowing responding with a `200` to requests to `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/index.php` from any request IP address, however it's incorrectly responding with a `403` to all other requests even when requested from the whitelisted IP address:

```
$ curl -I -H 'Host: www.example.com' 192.168.33.10
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

$ curl -I -H 'Host: www.example.com' 192.168.33.10/index.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

$ curl -I -H 'Host: www.example.com' 192.168.33.10/phpinfo.php
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

$ curl -I -H 'Host: www.example.com' 192.168.33.10/opcache.php
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

$ curl -I -H 'Host: www.example.com' 192.168.33.10/server-status
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

From `access.log`:

```
192.168.33.1 - - [15/Jun/2015:09:59:13 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "curl/7.37.1"
192.168.33.1 - - [15/Jun/2015:09:59:32 +0000] "HEAD /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "curl/7.37.1"
192.168.33.1 - - [15/Jun/2015:09:59:47 +0000] "HEAD /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1" 403 139 "-" "curl/7.37.1"
192.168.33.1 - - [15/Jun/2015:10:00:03 +0000] "HEAD /opcache.php HTTP/1.1" 403 139 "-" "curl/7.37.1"
192.168.33.1 - - [15/Jun/2015:10:00:22 +0000] "HEAD /server-status HTTP/1.1" 403 139 "-" "curl/7.37.1"
```

What changes do I need to make to my Apache config in order to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: For starters, try reloading Apache in case there is a config change that hasn't taken effect. If that doesn't work, try commenting out the `Require` line and reloading Apache and confirm the 403 goes away and it's not something else causing the 403.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was using ansible to provision the host, and it turns out the task to restart apache was silently failing due to a config error elsewhere. The config in the question was working correctly for all cases except `/server-status`, which needed it's own `Require ip 192.168.33.1` in order to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: Glad to hear it - I've posted this as an answer on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your config looks good - try reloading Apache in case there is a config change that hasn't taken effect.

Comment: @tommarshall - Since this was helpful to you, I'd appreciate an upvote and/or mark the answer as accepted so I can get credit.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are inserting the `LocationMatch` just for `index.php`. `LocationMatch` can be defined like a regexp, so you can try to add a regular expression for all the files you would need.

Somthing like:

```
<LocationMatch ^/(index.php|phpinfo.php|opcache.php)?$>
        Require all granted
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he doesn't want those other pages to be accessible to everyone, just / and /index.php

Comment: @sa289 is correct, I only want `/` & `/index.php` to be accessible to everyone.